# How to avoid asynchronous nature of scrollToVisibleRect causing intermittent timing issues

Tags: cocoa, nsview, appkit, nsscrollview

I am writing a Cocoa UI and am calling `NSView's scrollRectToVisible` repeatedly in a short space of time as a result of the user holding down a certain key (and hence repeatedly firing events on the main queue).

Through logging I can see that successive `keyDown()` events are firing prior to the `scrollRectToVisible` having completed its prior changing of the `visibleRect`. This is resulting in the subsequent `scrollRectToVisible` being called with incorrect inputs (namely the wrong starting visibleRect) and is leading to non-sensical UI behaviour. This happens about 50% of the time which I guess is to be expected dealing with an asynchronous problem.

How can I address this?

One way I can think of is by somehow turning `scrollRectToVisible` into a synchronous call. The problem is that it is an AppKit API and the method returns immediately with a boolean indicating whether it is going to scroll or not.

Comment: Are you using your own `NSTimer` to control the calls?

Comment: @mikeD No. Each successive `keyDown()` event triggers the `scrollRectToVisible` in a sequential manner. The `keyDown()` events are fired from literally just holding a single key on the keyboard down.

Comment: Have you tried overriding NSView's `- keyDown:` method in your view?

Comment: @mikeD I am overriding `keyDown:` in the `firstResponder` view.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the code in the view that responds to the `-keyDown:`.

This example controls the scrolling with a timer instead of the repeated keyDowns from holding the key.
I couldn't get the UI unwanted behavior, so I don't know if this will help.

```
- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)canBecomeKeyView {
    return YES;
}
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    if (timer == nil) {
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(doScroll:)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:YES];
    }
    NSLog(@"event %@ with Timer%@", theEvent, timer);
}
- (void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
    NSLog(@"keyUp timer:%@", timer);
    NSLog(@"event %@", theEvent);
}
- (void)doScroll:theTimer {
    NSEvent * current = [NSApp currentEvent]; //use this to parse
    NSLog(@"current press %@", current);
    [self scrollRectToVisible:NSMakeRect(self.visibleRect.origin.x + 10,
                                         self.visibleRect.origin.y + 10,
                                         self.bounds.size.width,
                                         self.bounds.size.height)];
}
```